# Asyncio: legitimate multiple threads with event loops use cases?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, event-loop, pyside6

Granted, given the GIL, classic `asyncio` design should focus on "single main thread with single event loop" in it. Nonetheless, are there legitimate "multiple threads with multiple event loops" use cases, which bring some architectural or performance advantages over the singular case? Please share.

Answer (score 1):

I never compare the performance of using multiple event loop in multiple threads.

As far as I know `asynchronous` is an event-driven architechture where single event loop is rely on single thread and the running function is this `event-loop` will wait for the trigger to get their time to run. This would becomes faster than threading (in theory) since we're no longer taking care of resource management (memory, cpu etc).

Threading basically will try to manage the resource in terms to make them run concurrently because its actually switching the resource usage.

But both is proposed to execute the program in parallel even if its not concurrent at a time. and for security, `asynchronous` is more thread safe since it's in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Found: one such use case is [QEventLoop <-> asyncio.EventLoop](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_async__minimal.html) "mutual stop-and-go hand-over" pattern in `PySide6`, when `QT` event loop stops itself, then allows `asyncio` event loop to run for a while, then `QT` event loop is back in control, all the while sharing the same thread.